# sort array in php, merging two values together

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array from a while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc...):

```
Array ( [item_id] => 1 [item_name] => name [foo] => bar )
```

How would I modify the array so it returns me:

```
Array ( [item_id] => 1 [item_name] => name - bar )
```

Comment: What are the rules for merging? I don't see any relevance between [item_name] and [foo] items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array['item_name'] = "{$array['item_name']} - {$array['foo']}";
unset($array['foo']);
```

or alternatively

```
$array = array(
  'item_id' => $array['item_id'],
  'item_name' => "{$array['item_name']} - {$array['foo']}"
);
```

Comment: shouldn't the second alternative use => instead of = between the keys and the values inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to merge [item_name] and [foo] values, then it's pretty easy:

```
$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return array(
        'item_id' => $item['item_id'],
        'item_name' => $item['item_name'] . ' - ' . $item['foo'],
    );
}, $input);
```